# How do I access a Qobject from one class to another class in PyQt5

Tags: python, json, pyqt5

I'm importing `interface.ui` to my application and it has a `QcomboBox` object. I use a `QThread` class to run a loop. I want to know how I could access my comboBox from another class(`QThread`)

```py
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('interface.ui', self)
        self.show()
        # self.comboBox is what I want to access

class WorkerThread(QThread):
        def run(self):
          #The other class and I want to access it here
```

I want to access `self.comboBox` from UI class to `WorkerThread` class. How do I access them from one class to another?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a few `QTextEdit` objects inside my application. When a user enters some information on this textedit boxes, clicking a button would dump them to a json file called `data.json`. But, if the user has selected a different comboBox option, I want the program to open a different json file and dump them to that json file. I've got this working.

As I have stored the data in `data.json` file for the default comboBox option, I open `data.json` to run my thread. (my thread uses the information in the json file).

If a user has selected a different comboBox option, I want the program to open the specific json file with the name of the currentText of the selected comboBox option, and get information from it and run my thread.

```py
class WorkerThread(QThread):
      def run(self):
          # if currentText of comboBox == 'default':
           with open('data.json') as f:
                 data = json.load(f)
          # else:
           with open(f'{currentText of comboBox}.json') as f:
                 data = json.load(f)
```

After I open the correct json file according to the text of the selected comboBox option, I start my loop.

```py
class WorkerThread(QThread):
      def run(self):
          # if currentText of comboBox == 'default':
           with open('data.json') as f:
                 data = json.load(f)
          # else:
           with open(f'{currentText of comboBox}.json') as f:
                 data = json.load(f)

           while True:
               print(data['my_data_of_the_opened_json'])
```

Comment: Please be more patient, and avoid deleting a question and repost it again, as users with enough reputation can still see the deleted posts. If and when people is able to review your question, it would be eventually opened.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An external thread should always work separately from the main UI thread. In fact, it should theoretically know *nothing* about the UI at all.

> If a user has selected a different comboBox option, I want the program to open the specific json file with the name of the currentText of the selected comboBox option, and get information from it and run my thread.

Your explanation already has the answer: the thread is run *after* the combo option is selected. This means that it should be created (or started) only at that point, not before.

Take this pseudo-code:

```
class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self, options):
        super().__init__()
        self.options = options

    def run(self):
        # do something with given options


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.startThread)

    def startThread(self, index):
        options = self.readFromJson(...)
        self.worker = Worker(options)
        self.worker.start()
```

There are cases for which a thread should be persistent, so it's created *and started* early, then it will wait until some processing is actually required; in those cases you can use a Queue and wait for some data.

```
from queue import Queue

class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            options = self.queue.get()
            # do something with options

    def queueOptions(self, options):
        self.queue.put(options)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.processOption)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.start()

    def processOption(self, index):
        options = self.readFromJson(...)
        self.worker.queueOptions(options)
```